# Incorrect legend display, and 'Warning: Computation failed in `stat_signif()`:' while running 'geom_signif' code

Tags: r, ggpubr

Good evening everybody,

I have two main problems with my graphs. The first one is that the legend displays incorrect shapes. Instead of showing a shape for mean, it displays a shape for outliers
[please see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjR1b.jpg).

Moreover, when I am trying to run

`geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Blank", "Vehicle - Vehicle")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")`  code, [I am getting the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKV2c.jpg)

I do not understand what value the R is demanding. In the beginning, I just thought that maybe because the data is not normalized and I am working with small values, it just has not had enough space on the y-axis to display `map_signif_level = TRUE`, but in the other example, it displayed the  `map_signif_level = TRUE` [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B89qi.jpg). So, I do not get why it sometimes displays `my_comparisons` correctly and sometimes not.

These are the following codes I used to produce the above graph:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
ggplot(PhospholipaseA2NOPo1, aes( x = Drug, y = Absorbance))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype='median'),size=1)+
  geom_point(aes(shape='mean'),size=3)+
  ggtitle("Comparison of the effect of Blank, Vehicle - Vehicle, Vehicle - Nicotinic Acid, SP - Vehicle, and SP -Nicotinic Acid on microglia - Phospholipase A2 Assay ") +
  labs(x = expression(paste("Treatment")))+
       ylab(expression(paste("Absrobance " ~ "(",   A[425], " - ", A[600] ~ nm, ")"))) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="black", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=3) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Blank", "Vehicle- Vehicle", "Vehicle - Nicotinic Acid", "SP - Vehicle", "SP - Nicotinic Acid"))+
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 0.50,
                     label.x = 3.25)+
          geom_boxplot(fill=c("#2171B5","#DEEBF7", "#CC79A7", "#CC79A7", "#CC79A7"), width=0.2,notch = FALSE)+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Blank", "Vehicle - Vehicle")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Blank", "Vehicle - Nicotinic Acid")), map_signif_level = TRUE,  colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Blank", "SP - Vehicle")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Blank", "SP - Nicotinic Acid")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Vehicle - Vehicle", "Vehicle - Nicotinic Acid")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Vehicle - Vehicle", "SP - Vehicle")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Vehicle - Vehicle", "SP - Nicotinic Acid")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Vehicle - Nicotinic Acid", "SP - Vehicle")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Vehicle - Nicotinic Acid", "SP - Nicotinic Acid")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("SP - Vehicle", "SP - Nicotinic Acid")), map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b")+
                  theme_bw() +
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#d3d3d3"),
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
              plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"))+
                   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#3142b0", 
                           size=8.9, angle=0),
                         axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#3142b0", 
                           size=8.9, angle=0))+
  scale_linetype_manual('Legend',values='solid')+
  scale_shape_manual('',values = 18)+
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(0.01, "cm"))
```

To produce the above graph, I have used  [the following data](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ao8fi7Xi8BskhLFcp-U0TCpYPcfI7g?e=Ci3bzz).

Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I have found the solution for my legend. First of all, while using scale_color_manual, we must add another `aes` mapping, in order to produce any type of legend. Therefore, I have added to the `geom_point()`, the `geom_point(aes(colour = "Blank (50 µM of dH20)"))`. Then, having an `aes` mapping I could produce my legend using the following codes:

```
scale_color_manual(name = "Final concentrations and volumes",
                     labels = c( "Blank (50 µL of dH20)", "Vehicle - Vehicle (10µL of dH20 + 10µL of dH20)", "Vehicle -Nicotinic Acid (10µL of dH20 + 10µL of 1mM)", "Sp-Vehicle (10µL of 5µM + 10µL of dH20)", "Sp-Nicotinic Acid( 10µL of 5µM + 10µL of 1mM)"),
                     values = c("Blank (50 µL of dH20)" =  "#B2182B", "Vehicle - Vehicle (10µL of dH20 + 10µL of dH20)" = "#D6604D", "Vehicle -Nicotinic Acid (10µL of dH20 + 10µL of 1mM)" = "#F4A582", "Sp-Vehicle (10µL of 5µM + 10µL of dH20)"= "#FDDBC7", "Sp-Nicotinic Acid(10µL of 5µM + 10µL of 1mM)"= "#D1E5F0"))+
```

Having, this I could change my legend position by using the following codes:

```
theme(legend.position = c(0, .97),
        legend.justification = c("left", "top"),
```

I also wanted the background of my legend to be transparent so I used the following code:

```
legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA))
```

As a result, I have got the following [outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2NrW.jpg)

Now, I am working on how to add a subscript to H20. I know that I could use `expression` or `bquote`, but so far I am getting something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQUya.jpg). I think I am messing up with "*", or something.

Answer (score 0):

This will be an incomplete answer, since I'm unsure how to fix the legend, but this is a good start:

```
PhospholipaseA2NOPo1<-structure(list(Drug = structure(c(1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                       5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                       2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Blank", "SP.N", "SP.V", "V.N", "V.V"
                                       ), class = "factor"), Absorbance = c(0.178155098, 0.281888047, 
                                                                            0.315468607, 0.395427286, 0.443773761, 0.274327232, 0.126408569, 
                                                                            0.160375886, 0.332019768, 0.328779358, 0.31918001, 0.202597307, 
                                                                            0.241052828, 0.332138474, 0.356656925, 0.329787758, 0.291912398, 
                                                                            0.264823437, 0.167194165, 0.176451481, 0.406376062, 0.28900749, 
                                                                            0.298281464, 0.181890255, 0.245723697, 0.350279692)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                      -26L))

library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
ggplot(PhospholipaseA2NOPo1, aes( x = Drug, y = Absorbance))+
  ggtitle("Comparison of the effect of Blank, Vehicle - Vehicle, Vehicle - Nicotinic Acid, SP - Vehicle, and SP -Nicotinic Acid on microglia - Phospholipase A2 Assay ") +
  labs(x = expression(paste("Treatment")))+
  ylab(expression(paste("Absrobance " ~ "(",   A[425], " - ", A[600] ~ nm, ")"))) +

  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Blank", "Vehicle- Vehicle", "Vehicle - Nicotinic Acid", "SP - Vehicle", "SP - Nicotinic Acid"))+
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 0.50,
                     label.x = 3.25)+
  geom_boxplot(fill=c("#2171B5","#DEEBF7", "#CC79A7", "#CC79A7", "#CC79A7"), width=0.2,notch = FALSE)+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="black", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=3) + 
  geom_signif(comparisons = split(t(combn(levels(PhospholipaseA2NOPo1$Drug), 2)), seq(nrow(t(combn(levels(PhospholipaseA2NOPo1$Drug), 2))))), 
              map_signif_level = TRUE, colour = "#cf1b1b", step_increase = .1)+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#d3d3d3"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#3142b0", 
                                   size=8.9, angle=0),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", color="#3142b0", 
                                   size=8.9, angle=0))+
  scale_linetype_manual('Legend',values='solid')+
  scale_shape_manual('Mean',values = )+
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(0.01, "cm"))
```

For the mean, you are putting the stat summary before the boxplot, so it won't show since the box is put on top of it. That being said, I don't know how to put it in the legend, so that's where this answer is incomplete. The technique you were using with the `geom_point(aes(shape='mean'),size=3)` will shape all points on the graph, not just the mean, which is why I removed it. As for the significance, I think the issue is that you were telling it to make significance based on the new x axis scale, rather than the actual names of the drugs themselves. So if you changed them to "SP.N" instead of "SP - Nicotinic Acid" I think it will work. Out of simplicity, I just added one line to compare all levels.

Best of luck, hopefully somebody better with graphs will be able to help out more with the legend!

Comment: Wow, for clarification as I have never crossed by `structure(list(...)` code, could you please explain what do they  `1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,` represent? Thank you for your time

Comment: I put your data into a dataframe, then used "dput()" to help recreate it. From what I've seen on many posts, people will use dput so it's easy for someone else to copy and use the data. Check ```?dput``` to read more about it since it's probably a lot better of a description than I gave lol. I'm not entirely sure what the 1L info is, but it's something to do with the structure of the data frame itself, so probably a length or something?

Comment: Thank you. I will read about the `?dput` as based on your answer, it changes everything dramatically and makes things easier. I thought that for significance, you have to add each separate line of  `geom_signif(comparisons = list(c` for each significant value you want to show.  But it seems you need to put your data in the `class = "data.frame"` and job done.